# Intercambiar entre dialogo o actividad en base del tamaño del dispositivo en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo una lista que quiero que al editar un item, se abre una actividad si está corriendo en móvil o bien un dialogo si está en tableta.

la detección de si es smartphone o tableta ya lo tengo. es solo como se implementaria que un mismo proceso de edición con todos sus elementos en pantalla, se comparten entre una actividad y un dialogo.

Comment: Para implementar una vista ya sea en una actividad o en un Dialogo, se tiene la funcion setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); , en ese orden de ideas, tanto el dialogo como el activity quedarian visualmente igual segun como se haya configurado el layout a implementar, no se si es a eso a lo que se refiere

Comment: y su computación no me queda claro es decir el control del layout, proceso de los controles etc... porque en un dialogo se puede cargar algo que extenda de una activity?

Comment: Pareciera que se corto el comentario que iba a escribir, el caso es que en android uno crea una serie de Layout que van en el folder res.layout, estos son xml, y estos layout pueden ser cargados tanto por Dialogs como por Activities, ya en el caso de la funcionalidad tendria que hacer todo centralizado en una clase que pueda ser llamada de la misma forma tanto por el activity como por el dialog, si estoy interpretando mal, me dices